# Linux server A iptables INPUT policy is set ACCEPT,server B disable firewall, but I can't detection A's httpd port from server B

Tags: iptables

Linux server A iptables INPUT policy is set ACCEPT,server B disable firewall, but I can't detection A's httpd port from server B.

```
# server A
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Fri Oct 16 14:29:37 2015
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]   # <--see here
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [151:126429]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Oct 16 14:29:37 2015
```

Comment: :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]   # <--default is ACCEPT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an ACCEPT target for RELATED, ESTABLISHED connections only.
You should add a rule for port 80/443/whatever_port_used_by_httpd with (assuming port 80):

```
# iptables -I INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

An useful thing is to add a LOGnDROP (or LOGnREJECT here) instead of simply DROP (or REJECT) during troubleshooting.

Comment: Thank you!You mean default policy just for  RELATED, ESTABLISHED connections only?

Comment: I meant, the default policy (ACCEPT) was not reached since you've a REJECT fallback rule, and the only one accepted there was for connections in either RELATED or ESTABLISHED state.

Comment: So thanks,I see,I used to think
[-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited]
just REJECT icmp packages.